# C program pointer not holding valid address still not giving segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers

The segmentation fault error in C programs occurs because we try to access address not allocated to current program's resource.

I was trying to get a segmentation fault error with the below code. And I am not able to understand why in main function the last call for function check() do not give segmentation fault.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int check(char * memptr);
int foo(char * memptr);

int main()
{
    char mem = 'a';
    char * memptr = NULL;
    char * cantcatch;
    check(&mem);                        // valid pointer
    check(memptr);                      // error case, but can be checked
    check(cantcatch);                   // error case, but can't catch
    return 0;
}

int check(char * memptr)
{
    if (NULL == memptr)
    {
        printf("\n  error, function foo() not called \n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n After = %c, ret val = %d, Before = %c, Before = %d \n", \
        *memptr, foo(memptr), *memptr, *memptr);
    }
    return 0;
}

int foo(char * memptr)
{
    *memptr = 'b';
    return 0;
}
```

If I try to print the 'memptr' pointer then it gives this segmentation fault error.

Any hint in understanding this will be greatly helpful.

Comment: You have not initialised `cantcatch` therefore whatever you try to do with it is undefined. That does not mean it *will* cause a segfault: the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: I love that undefined behaviour definitions always end with "[...] means that the behaviour is undefined". :)

Comment: The _behaviour_ _is_ _undefined_ means, can you please explain a little more in detail?

Comment: basically: anything goes, anything can happen, segfault, your computer burning, POSIX people raiding your fridge... That's a joke of course but it just means that what happens cannot be predicted.

Comment: The *behaviour is undefined* means that the C standard does not specify what will happen in these circumstances: the answer from @Tomer says it well, though there may be more than the two outcomes he states.

Comment: You mean what ever code we write in C must not be left undefined for the desired working of the code, in other words better to initialize all variables we declare. Is that correct?

Comment: @Mithun "Undefined" here refers to "undefined behavior", which is a precise technical term in the C standard, it doesn't mean "not initialized" or "not specified". The standard(s) specify exactly which are the sources of undefined behavior. For example, dereferencing an invalid pointer is a source of undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the value of "cantcatch" - which is undefined (random value).
If the value is out of the memory scope of your program - then the program will segfault.

If it's within the scope of your program then the program will not crash but potentially cause corruption to memory.

These invalid read/writes can easily be caught by memory profiling tools such as "Valgrind".

Comment: The _random_ _value_ means that the multiple run of this code may cause segmentation fault at some time at least?

Comment: Not only the value is undefined, the whole program is.

Comment: In theory yes. However, there is always the possibility that the value will not be completely random (e.g. be the exact same random value on each execution) - you could print the value of the pointer each run - and see what happens.